# Are friends in c++ mutual?

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Friend scope in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437250/friend-scope-in-c)

Are friends in C++ mutual?

Comment: Just like in real life: one-way relationships exist, even when you believe they are mutual :)

Comment: This question made me smile :D

Comment: Friend is already a questionable construct and can cause code to be untidy from an access point of view. At least making it one way reducing the degree that the protection is compromised

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class bar
{
private:
   void barMe();
};

class foo
{
private:
   void fooMe();

friend bar;
};
```

In the above example foo class can't call barMe()
You need to define the classes this way in order that the friend be mutual:

```
class foo; // forward
class bar
{
private:
   void barMe();

friend foo;
};

class foo
{
private:
   void fooMe();

friend bar;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The friend relationship is only one-way in general - but there is nothing to stop you declaring Class A a friend of class B AND class B a friend of class A. So a mutual relationship can be established