# Can the "friend" relationship be transferred among C++'s class?

Tags: c++, class, friend

suppose class A is the friend of class B, and B is friend of class C, is A the friend of C or C the friend of A, or both, or none ?

Comment: Friendship is not transferrable by friendship or by inheritance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Friend scope in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437250/friend-scope-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, friendship in C++ is not transitive.

From the C++03 standard, 11.4-8:

> Friendship is neither inherited nor transitive. Example:

```
class A {
  friend class B;
  int a;
};

class B {
  friend class C;
};

class C {
  void f(A* p)
  {
    p->a++; 
    // error: C is not a friend of A
    // despite being a friend of a friend
  }
};

class D : public B {
  void f(A* p)
  {
    p->a++; 
    // error: D is not a friend of A
    // despite being derived from a friend
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

None. See the [C++FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.4):

> Friendship isn't inherited, transitive, or reciprocal

Answer (score 0):

C++ class friendship does not propagate in this way, so A class wouldn't be a friend of C class. It's like on Facebook, if one of your friends makes friends with someone, that person doesn't become your friend automatically =)