# Redefinition of 'Stack' as different kind of symbol

Tags: c++, class, templates

One of the template classes exercises in my C++ class asks to make those two classes work:

file node.h

```
#ifndef node_h
#define node_h


template<typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    friend class Stack;
    Node(T value, Node *next);
    T value;
    Node *next;
};

#endif /* node_h */
```

and file stack.h

```
#ifndef stack_h
#define stack_h

#include "node.h"

template<typename T>
class Stack  // ERROR HERE!
{
public:
    Stack() : top(0) {}
    void push(T value);
    T pop();
private:
    Node<T> *top;
};

template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T value)
{
    top = new Node<T>(value, top);
}

template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    T result = top->value;
    top = top->next;
    return result;
}

#endif /* stack_h */
```

I'm getting a "Redefinition of 'Stack' as different kind of symbol" thrown by the compiler. I know it has to do with the declaration of Stack as a friend class in the node.h file, but if I remove that line, then Stack does not get access to the node's private members. Why is this issue occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
friend class Stack;
```

You need

```
friend class Stack<T>;
```

In order to actually get this to compile though, I had to also add a forward reference to `Stack` above `Node`.  <del>[I didn't think this was necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890756/how-come-forward-declaration-is-not-needed-for-friend-class-concept), so maybe someone can explain why a forward reference is needed here.</del> Alternatively, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967521/class-template-with-template-class-friend-whats-really-going-on-here) suggests `template<typename U> friend class Stack;` works without a forward reference, but this makes `Stack<char>` a friend of `Node<int>` which I don't think is the OPs intent.  Maybe someone could clarify. Complies with `g++ 7.2.0`

```
template<typename T> class Stack;

template<typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    friend class Stack<T>;
    Node(T value, Node *next);
    T value;
    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492062/why-does-a-c-friend-class-need-a-forward-declaration-only-in-other-namespaces

Comment: @MarkMucha I think this one is more clear in the OPs case. I'll edit my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967521/class-template-with-template-class-friend-whats-really-going-on-here

Comment: Now I have a second issue though where the push() method cannot find an appropriate Node constructor.

    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "Node<int>::Node(int, Node<int>*)", referenced from:
           Stack<int>::push(int) in main.o

Should I be asking for help with that here or in a new question?

Comment: Yeah. Make sure you implement it. You only declared it in the code you pasted. Replace `Node(T value, Node *next);` with `Node(T v, Node *n) : value(v), next(n) {}`