# How friend specifier does work in c++?

Tags: c++, friend

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
    friend void foo(){ printf("%d\n",_a); }
public:
    A(int);
private:
    static const int _a=5;
};

class B
{
    friend void foo(){ printf("%d\n",_a); }
private:
    static const int _a=6;
};

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

After compiling I've the following errors:

```
an_test.cpp:14:14: error: redefinition of ‘void foo()’
an_test.cpp:5:14: error: ‘void foo()’ previously defined here
an_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
an_test.cpp:21:6: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [an_test.o] Error 1
```

I think that functions defined with friend specifier are external linkage. So why an_test.cpp:21:6: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope?

Comment: First of all: Don't define them inside the class. That makes no sense for using `friend` at all.

Comment: fix your first error `redefinition of ‘void foo()’` and try again. `foo` is not in scope because compiler failed to create it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, It still makes sense defining it in the class, but not without any parameters.

Comment: inline friend function can only be look up using ADL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing *linkage* with scoping. In your code, the **scope** of both `foo()` definitions are inside their respective classes, so `main()` cannot see their definitions.

If you want `foo()` to be visible in `main()`, you need to move its *declaration* outside, and make a `friend` declaration inside the class.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
    friend void foo(A a);
    public:
    A(int) {}
    private:
    static const int _a=5;
};

void foo(A a){ printf("%d\n",a._a); }

int main()
{
    foo(A(5));
}
```

The following would also work, where the definition is inside and there is a declaration outside.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
friend void foo(A a){ printf("%d\n",a._a); }
public:
    A(int) {}
private:
    static const int _a=5;
};

 void foo(A a);


int main()
{
    foo(A(5));
}
```

Comment: @Mankarse, I was just about to do the other test.

Comment: But what about this quote "A function first declared in a friend declaration has external linkage (3.5)."?? In my case all function declared with friend declaration but they aren't visible inside the main().

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c) for the difference between external linkage and internal linkage. It has nothing to do with scoping.

Answer (score 1):

I found something about C++ Friend functions that may help you know why the errors occur:

[C++ Friend Functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_friend_functions.htm)

Note that:

> A friend function of a class is defined outside that class' scope but
>   it has the right to access all private and protected members of the
>   class. Even though the prototypes for friend functions appear in the
>   class definition, friends are not member functions. A friend can be a
>   function, function template, or member function, or a class or class
>   template, in which case the entire class and all of its members are
>   friends.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link about friend scope can answer your question

[Friend scope in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437250/friend-scope-in-c/437507#437507)

"Foo are friend of A" does not mean "Foo" are friend of "An_test"