# C++ accessing private members through pointer argument

Tags: c++

```
class Link
{
private:
    string value;
    Link* succ;
    Link* prev;
public:
    Link(string v, Link* s = nullptr, Link* p = nullptr)
    : value(v), succ(s), prev(p) { }
Link* insert(Link* p)
{
    if(p == nullptr) return this;
    p->succ = this;
    if(this->prev) this->prev->succ = p->prev;
    p->prev = this->prev;
    this->prev = p;

    return p;
}
};

int main()
{
    Link* language = new Link{Link("C++", nullptr, nullptr)};
    language = language->insert(new Link("Python", language, nullptr));

    return 0;
}
```

In the book, programming principles and practice, there is a chapter where you implement a part of a list and here's the code.

In the above code, insert() takes Link* as an argument and uses -> to change what it's pointing at(Link* succ, prev) directly. But both succ and prev are private members of the class so I don't understand how it's possible for insert() to access them directly.

Comment: Answer this question -- Using your reasoning, how would/could `prev` and `succ` ever get changed if they're `private`?  A class is allowed to change its internals.

Comment: Access restriction applies to the _class_, not to the _objects_. Any method in the class can access any field of any object in the class. It is code outside the class that has restricted access.

Comment: You are alway s friends of yourself (and your clones). https://stackoverflow.com/a/437507/14065

Comment: Semi-related note: `private` and `protected` only make it harder to make access mistakes. They can't stop deliberate attempts to circumvent the access restrictions and they do not make it impossible to screw up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above code, `insert()` takes `Link*` as an argument and uses `->` to change what it's pointing at(`Link* succ, prev`) directly. But both `succ` and `prev` are `private` members of the class so I don't understand how it's possible for `insert()` to access them directly.

In a member function of a class, it is possible to access the `private` members of the class. Since `insert()` is a member function of the `Link`, you can access the `private` members of the class (`prev` and `succ`) in it. You can not only access the `prev` and `succ` of the implicit object, i.e. `this->prev` and `this->succ`, but you can access the `prev` and `succ` members of any instance of the class.

Form https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access (emphasis mine):

> A private member of a class can only be accessed by the members and friends of that class, **regardless of whether the members are on the same or different instances**: